Is spanner a subgraph?
I've recently came across Spanners and Emulators, which seem to be pretty much the same thing, apart from whether or not the approximation is multiplicative or additive. However, I saw that a $k$-spanner is defined to be a subgraph $H$ of $G$ such that it preserves distances, up to a multiplicative factor of $k$. My question is: Must $E_{H} \subseteq E_{G}$? Possibly, I could introduce new edges, that will allow me reachability between multiple pairs of vertices, thus reducing the total number of edges. After all, our main goal in Spanners/Emulators, is to reduce the number of edges? As long as they preserve distances, why must they be original edges?
